# Career path for a Technical Engagement Manager

Tags: career-development

I have searched and didn't find anything that answers my question; I am looking for information on a generic trajectory for a Technical Engagement Manager and where does it lead to. An engagement manager as the name implies manages client relationships and works to build those relationships and grow them. Technical implies these engagements are based on software services, software dev., cloud services etc. (Saas, PaaS, *aaS etc.)

I would love to hear if anyone else has risen through the ranks of being an Engagement manager or where this role leads eventually (even in context of specific organizations is fine).

E.g. Trajectory for someone starting out in Software dev. could potentially be: Software Dev., Sr. Software Dev., Lead Software Dev., Team Lead, Architect or Engineering Manager, Sr. Engineering Manager or Sr. Architect, Associate Director or Associate Principal Architect, Director or Principal Architect etc.

The above is kind of what I am looking for in context of this role.

Thanks for your input.

Comment: Do you have some sort of business degree or experience? I anticipate you needing a Business Degree (at minimum) and likely an MBA if you want to move outside of general management to upper management in most countries/locales. Only real way to avoid this is to start a company yourself.

Comment: I have a BS in IT/Software engineering. I am very strong technically and an MBA is on my radar, just can't justify the cost so probably will see if I can get employer to cover,

Comment: Welcome to the site John. Unfortunately The Workplace's Q&A format is not suitable for your question since you're asking about specific career paths or career advice and you're basically soliciting opinions. We *can* answer specific questions on how to handle a workplace situation, accomplish a goal or come to a decision on a particular problem. If you can reword your question to fit those criteria please do so, otherwise your post will likely be closed.

Comment: @Lilienthal: thanks for your feedback. Let me see if I can reword it to fit the QA format. But to me asking about a career path is a valid question that has an answer; i don't necessarily view it as opinionated. E.g. for a software dev path would be: software dev, sr. software dev., lead software dev., team lead, engineering manager, sr. engineering manager, associate director, director etc. Granted some folks might be able to jump past a particular rank to a higher level but that is a generic trajectory and that is what I am looking for.

Comment: [Chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3060/the-water-cooler) might be a better place for this discussion, I will ping you there and it should give you access.